# How can I remove the Chromecast volume button?

Tags: volume, chromecast

I developed https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kunert.einsteinstictactoe. When the user hits the Chromecast button the first time he is able to connect to a Chromecast device. If he hits it the second time after being connected he is able to adjust the volume or to disconnect.

As my application currently doesn't support sound I want to hide the volume adjustment.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You need to define your own `MediaRouteDialogFactory` and in there, return your own `MediaRouteControllerDialogFragment` implementation. In your implementation of that fragment, in `onCreateControllerDialog`, you need to set `setVolumeControlEnabled(false)`. See the package `com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.cast.dialog.video` in CCL which has all of these for its implementation.

Comment: Update: note that the v22 of MeiaRouter support library has removed the volume.